# Why am I getting as TS(1005) error on a line of code (below)?

Tags: javascript

```
progress-bar2 = document.getElementById("progressbarfull");
```

I am fairly new to coding and the error is to do with the '=' symbol but I'm not sure why..

I have changed the name of the class to something with out the hyphen and it is not that and I'm using `progress-bar2` in my HTML and CSS I am also using other `= document.getElementbyID/getElementbyClassName`

I hope this make sense and if someone could help I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Did you initialize progress-bar2? Ex: `let progress-bar2 = ...`

Comment: You can't use `-` in a variable name, it's the subtraction operator. Use `_` instead.

Comment: ohhh okay I wasn't aware of that, thank you! teaching myself means I have gaps in my knowledge

Answer (score 0):

JS variables are different from CSS classes (you can use any name you desire in JS, no matter what you decide to use in your CSS).

JS variables may include only letters, numbers, and underscores.

JS variables can't start with a number.

---

Chose another name for your variable, `progressBar2`, which is a valid equivalent for your CSS class name.

```js
var progressBar2 = document.getElementById("progressbarfull");
```